# Django generic relation admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.9.9 with generic relations and in the `admin` site, I have to manually type in the Object ID. Is there any method so that I can select an object from a list like a regular foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ready to try packages for what you'd like:

- [Django-genericdropdown](https://github.com/peppelorum/Django-genericdropdown) :

  > A simple dropdown the make the hassle of picking to the right object
  >   when using generic relations
- [django-gfklookupwidget](https://github.com/mqsoh/django-gfklookupwidget) :

  > A widget to replace the object_id in a generic relation with a search
  >   link. It will open a popup to select a related item based on the
  >   content_type field. It supports inlines.